# How to increase button size in javascript of whatsapp

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Everything is working fine but the button is too small.
How to increase size of button?

Comment: It's just an `<a>` tag. You can apply any CSS you like to it. Start with `font-size` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) CSS property to make the text of the link larger.

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" style="font-size: 1.3em;">Share via Whatsapp</a>
   <!--The font-size here is set to 1.3em. Alter it to suit your needs.-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the button an class:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" class="whatsappbutton">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

And add some CSS. I'm guessing you don't have a stylesheet linked, so just add this to the `<head>` element and make any changes you'd like:

```
<style>
  .whatsappbutton {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
</style>
```